# HEVC transform quantized coefficients using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, hevc

i'm using the HEVC codec with ffmpeg(version 2.7.2 ). Since I'm not able to write a one-line command in order to read/save the quantized transformed coefficients for each CU and frame, I would like to know if anyone can help me modify the original files in the libavcodec library?

Answer (score 0):

No CLI option available to save the quantized coefficients. If you need to modify the source code for this purpose, below function is the right place to start with

> hls_transform_unit() @ libavcodec\hevc.c